# JAXB and Jersey - returning a list of objects extending an abstract class

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey

I'm creating a REST service and I want to return a List of objects. So I got something like this:

```
@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("items/")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
public List<AClass> getItems() {            

    List<AClass> list = db.getItems();      
    return list;

}
```

where db.getItems() returns a list of objects that are a type of subclasses of AClass. AClass is an abstract class. Objects have more fields added. But these additional fields are not generated in an XML. How can I have them in a result?

Comment: So dont you need to have jaxb classes for the subclasses and return the list of subclasses. I dont think returning list of baseclass will help you here.

Comment: Have you looked at [XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html)?

Comment: Yes, it's working now, thanks! I'd tried before but for some reason it wasn't working then... anyway, it is now, so thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html)? That annotation will allow you to bind subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

// Client

```
package com.project.rest.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Client {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String lang;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Client(Long id, String email, String lang) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.lang = lang;
    }

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
    return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLang() {
    return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Client [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", lang=" + lang + "]";
    }

}
```

//ClientService

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;

@Path("/client")
public class ClientService {

    @POST
    @Path("/sendList")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJSONList(List<Client> clientList) {

        String output = "consumeJSONList Client : " + clientList.toString() + "\n\n";

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

//JerseyClient

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;
import com.project.rest.model.Device;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

public class JerseyClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

    List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
    clientList.add(new Client(1L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(2L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(3L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client c = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(clientConfig);

    WebResource webResource = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/project_rest/rest/client/sendList");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, clientList);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed sendClientList: HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println("sendClientList... Server response .... \n");
    System.out.println(output);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
}
}
```

//POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.10-b01</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
```