# Jersey API returns ArrayList with Objects without Subclass properties

Tags: java, json, arraylist, subclass

With my API, I have to return Object (`Playlist`) with has an ArrayList in it with Objects(`Track`).

Playlist.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

@XmlRootElement
public class Playlist {
    private String owner;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Track> tracks;

    public Playlist() {
        this.tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    }

    public Playlist(String owner, String name, Track[] tracks) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.name = name;
        this.tracks = new ArrayList<Track>(Arrays.asList(tracks));
    }

    public void addTrack(Track track) {
        this.tracks.add(track);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "tracks")
    public ArrayList<Track> getTracks() {
        return this.tracks;
    }

    public void changeName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

However, `Track` is a Superclass of the actual classes used `Song` and `Video`.
In the `ArrayList`, only `Song Objects` and `Video Objects` are found, which have a few separate properties.
For example, a `Song` is part of an `String:album` and a `Video` has a `String:description`.

The JSON returned by the API only shows the shared properties from `Track` but not the `album` a `Song` belongs to or the `description` given with the `Video`.

How can I fix this?

Activity

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

@Path("/api/playlist")
public class PlaylistActivityREST {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Playlist getPlaylist() {
        Playlist playlist = new Playlist(
                "Owner",
                "Playlist name",
                new Track[]{
                        new Song(
                                "Ed Sheeran",
                                "Galway Girl",
                                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87gWaABqGYs",
                                ((Integer) (60 * 3 + 19)).longValue(),
                                "÷"
                        ),
                        new Video(
                                "Ed Sheeran",
                                "Shape of You",
                                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8",
                                ((Integer) (60 * 4 + 24)).longValue(),
                                25177705,
                                new GregorianCalendar(2017, 5, 3),
                                "÷. Out Now: https://atlanti.cr/yt-album"
                        )
                }
        );

        return playlist;
    }
}
```

Song.java

```
public class Song extends Track {

    private String album;

    public Song(String performer, String title, String url, long duration, String album) {
        super(performer, title, url, duration);
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }
}
```

Video.java

```
public class Video extends Track {
    private int playCount;
    private Calendar publicationDate;
    private String description;

    public Video(String performer, String title, String url, long duration, int playCount, Calendar publicationDate, String description) {
        super(performer, title, url, duration);
        this.playCount = playCount;
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPlayCount() {
        return playCount;
    }

    public String getPlayCountThousandsSeperator() {
        return String.format(Locale.US, "%,d", this.playCount).replace(',', '.');
    }

    public void setPlayCount(int playCount) {
        this.playCount = playCount;
    }

    public Calendar getPublicationDate() {
        return publicationDate;
    }

    public void setPublicationDate(Calendar publicationDate) {
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Track.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Track {
    private String performer;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private long duration;

    public Track() {
    }

    public Track(String performer, String title, String url, long duration) {
        this.performer = performer;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getPerformer() {
        return performer;
    }

    public void setPerformer(String performer) {
        this.performer = performer;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getParsedDuration() {
        return this.getDuration() / 60 + ":" + this.getDuration() % 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your Song/ Video class? How does it look like? From the code it looks proper that you are passing the required things in the constructor, but still... If you could!

Comment: Question updated, added Song, Video and Track classes

Answer (score 0):

After more hours of research, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018029/jaxb-and-jersey-returning-a-list-of-objects-extending-an-abstract-class) and it works for this problem as well.

It now starts with

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Song.class,Video.class}) //This fixed it
public class Playlist { ... } // Omitting unchanged code
```